# Linear Programming Sensitivity to Matrix

Tags: reference-request, optimization, linear-programming, convex-optimization

Consider a linear program in the following standard form:
\begin{align*}
&\max  c^T x &\\
&\mbox{subject to:}\\
&A x \preceq b\\
&x \succeq 0
\end{align*}

Its dual is
\begin{align*}
&\min  b^T y &\\
&\mbox{subject to:}\\
&A^T y \succeq c\\
&y \succeq 0
\end{align*}

Let $x^*$ and $y^*$ be optimal primal and dual solutions, respectively. Let $\nu = c^T x^* = b^T y^*$ be the optimal value. Suppose for simplicity that the optimal solutions are unique (i.e., we have non-degeneracy for both primal and dual). It is well known from basic sensitivity analysis that the optimal value is differentiable with respect to $b$ and $c$ at that point, and we have $$\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial c_j} = x^*_j$$ and $$\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial b_i} = y^*_i.$$ The proof of these facts is also quite simple.

What I wasn't able to find, however, was an authoritative and simple treatment of sensitivity with respect to entries of the matrix $A$. In particular, suppose we modify just the a single entry $a_{ij}$ of the matrix $A$. What is the partial derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $a_{ij}$, in the non-degenerate case (i.e., where $\nu$ is differentiable)? Playing around with it, I'm pretty sure the answer is the following:

$$\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial a_{ij}} = - y^*_i x^*_j$$

I even have the outlines of a (sketchy) "proof", though it is not as simple or "clean" as I would like. I'm reluctant to spend significant time and effort on this, since such a basic fact should certainly be known and written down clearly in a book somewhere.

Does anyone know a simple proof of this fact, or can point me to a reference which provides such a proof? Or am I way off base here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I have figured this out! I am going to assume we have primal and dual problems:
\begin{array}?
(P) &&\max& c^Tx &&& (D) &&\min& b^Ty \\
&&\text{s.t.}& Ax \leq b &&&  && \text{s.t.}& A^Ty \geq c \\
&&           &  x \geq 0 &&&  &&            &    y \geq 0
\end{array}
Which we can write in the equivalent forms (which are not directly duals of each other, but are related).
\begin{array}?
(P')        &&\max& c^Tx &&& (D')&&\min& b^Ty \\
&&\text{s.t.}& Ax+u = b &&&   && \text{s.t.}& A^Ty - v = c \\
&&           &  x, u \geq 0 &&&  &&            &    y, v \geq 0
\end{array}

Note that $\nu = c^T x^*$ and $c$ is constant, so we have that $\frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}} = c^T\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial a_{ij}}.$ Here $\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial a_{ij}}$ is the (column) vector whose $j$th entry is $\frac{\partial x^*_j}{\partial a_{ij}}$. Similarly we have $\frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}} = b^T\frac{\partial y^*}{\partial a_{ij}}.$

Finally, we note that $\nu = {y^*}^TAx^* - {v^*}^Tx^* = {y^*}^TAx^*$ since, by complimentary slackness, ${v^*}^Tx^*=0$ for any optimal primal solution $x^*$ and optimal dual slack variables $v^*$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}}
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}} \left({y^*}^TAx^*\right) \tag{1}\\
    &= \left(\frac{\partial y^*}{\partial a_{ij}}\right)^TAx^* + y^*_ix^*_j +
            {y^*}^TA\left(\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial a_{ij}}\right) \tag{2}\\
    &= \left(\frac{\partial y^*}{\partial a_{ij}}\right)^Tb + y^*_ix^*_j +
            c^T\left(\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial a_{ij}}\right) \tag{3}\\
    &= \left(\frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}}\right) + y^*_ix^*_j +
            \left(\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial a_{ij}}\right) \tag{4}\\
\Rightarrow - \frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}} &= y^*_ix^*_j  \tag{5}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}} &= - y^*_ix^*_j  \tag{5}\\
\end{align}

Comment: I suspect you forgot some inequalities in the primal and/or dual (these LPs are not duals as stated). Which LPs did you mean, exactly?

Comment: These LPs are duals as stated. Equality constraints in the primal correspond to free variables (ie NOT non-negative/non-positive) in the dual and vice versa.

Comment: I agree. I must have been looking at an old version or something

Comment: I did update the answer as this form is clearer and more useful, but the old version was still correct.

Comment: Looks right to me. I guess you can replace Ax* by b and y*^T A by c in the third equality by complementary slackness. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ and $v$ be vectors of slack variables for the primal and dual, respectively. Thus $A x^* + u = b$ and $A^T y^* - v = c$. Then we can see that
\begin{equation}
\nu = c^T x^* = (Ay^*-v)^Tx^* = {y^*}^T(Ax^*) - v^T x^* \tag{0}
\end{equation}
And thus
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}} 
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}}\left (y^*_ia_{ij}x^*_j \right) \tag{1}\\
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}}\left (y^*_ia_{ij}x^*_j \right) \tag{2}\\
    &= a_{ij}y^*_i\frac{\partial x^*_j}{\partial a_{ij}} + a_{ij}y^*_i\frac{\partial y^*_i}{\partial a_{ij}}x^*_j + y^*_ix^*_j \tag{3}\\
    &= a_{ij}y^*_i\frac{-x^*_j}{a_{ij}} + a_{ij}y^*_i\frac{-y^*_i}{a_{ij}}x^*_j + y^*_ix^*_j \tag{4}\\
    &= -y^*_ix^*_j \tag{5}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. But why is it obvious that $\frac{\partial x^*_j}{\partial a_{ij}} = - \frac{x^*_j}{a_{ij}}$? One could imagine that changes in $a_{ij}$ can  affect $x$ in a somewhat more nuanced way that is not localized to just $x^*_j$, and therefore $x^*_j$ might go down by less than that... I suspect I'm wrong to worry about this, but I'm not quite sure why I'm wrong...

Comment: Since we are assuming there is a unique optimal solution, we know it must be a basic feasible solution, and thus be associated with a basis. Assuming non-degeneracy this is the only optimal basis and, for a small enough change in $a_{ij}$ the optimal basis won't change. Thus $x^*_j$ is the only variable that can change to accommodate the change in $a_{ij}$. If the basis associated with $x^*$ is degenerate, I would suspect that $\frac{\partial\nu}{\partial a_{ij}$ does not exist.

Comment: I think I can come up with a counterexample. Suppose the optimal basis is given by the following equations:

$$x_1 - x_2 = 0$$
$$x_1 + x_2 = 1$$

Clearly, the solution is $x_1 =x_2 = 1/2$. Now suppose vary the coefficient of $x_1$ in the first equation, let's call it $a$, initially at $1$...

$$a x_1 - x_2 = 0$$
$$x_1 + x_2 = 1$$

We can come up with a closed form solution to the above system as a function of $a$. In particular, $x_1 = \frac{1}{1+a}$. The derivative of $x$ w.r.t. $a$ is $- \frac{1}{(1+a)^2}$, which at $a=1$ is $-\frac{1}{4}$. This is not equal to $-x_1/a = -1/2$.

Comment: Ah yes you are absolutely right, I was wrong. You would need to look at all of the basic variables (and the dual basic variables) as a function of $a$ and compute the derivate of ${y^*}^TAx^* - v^Tx^*$ more carefully.